# I can't get my android emulator to work - keep getting a build failed error

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio-code, error-handling, android-emulator

Here is the full error I've received:

I've tried just redownloading the repo and I'm not even sure what else to do as I'm new to using                 Android emulators.
I've tried redownloading yarn as well.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'FavAnswerNew'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5.1' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
             - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5.1')
```